# How to catch any c++ standard exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I know that in C++ you can catch an exception of any data type using:

```
try {
  // throw exception here
} catch (...) {
  // handle exception here
}
```

But I want to catch any C++ standard exception, such as `std::logic_error`, `std::out_of_range`, and not ones of other data types such as `string` or `int`. How can I catch only the C++ standard exceptions only? I want to call `exp.what()` on the passed in C++ standard exception object, and that's not possible using the above code.

Comment: [hint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard exceptions derive from `std::exception`, so catch that instead:

```
try {
    // throw exception here
}
catch (const std::exception &e) {
    // handle exception here
}
```